# get the extension of the uploaded file in jsp using apache common fileupload

Tags: jsp, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

Initially i started with storing the images in database for security and easy backup purpose.

so i never faced the problems to get the extension of the file.

Now i am facing problem because database load.

So i planned that i will store the images in a folder and i will show those images.

but i need to rename those file and store the extension in database so that i can directly access.

But as i was string the images in database, i never cared about the extension of the file.

As i have to access the image file, i must know the extension.

How to get the extension of the file in Apache common fileupload.

Comment: If you can serve the images from the database without knowing the file extension, why wouldn't you be able to do the same thing from the file system? The browser doesn't know (and doesn't care) where the stream of bytes comes from. It cares about its mime type, but you must have a way to know it already. And if you know it, you should be able to decide which file extension to use.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't really understood @JBNizet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I have done it in my code. item is a  FileItem or a FileItemStream object.

```
String format = "none";
String fileName = item.getName();
int index = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
if(index > 0){
               format = fileName.substring(index+1);
               format = format.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: What if, a file has an extension like `archiveFile.tar.gz`?

Comment: The question at the top specified image files. In your case you could try using  int index = fileName.indexOf(".");